# How can I attach a remote java debugger for debugging a rundeck plugin?

Tags: java, debugging, plugins, rundeck

I am currently developing a custom java plugin for Rundeck.
Is it possible attach a remote debugger on the java process to better understand and debug throughout the process?

Something like adding this flag to rundeck jvm:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with this flag it works (without the asterisk and colon):

```java
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=<debug_port_to_listen>,server=y,suspend=n
```

e.g (Rundeck WAR based instance):

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=<debug_port_to_listen>,server=y,suspend=n -jar rundeck.war
```

Comment: I was able to achieve that by launching Rundeck as follows:
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 -jar rundeck-4.6.1-20220914.war

Comment: Great, yes, that is the way :)